# Suggestions for breadboard routing of hard switch full-bridge circuit

Tags: dc-dc-converter, breadboard, routing

I need to do some test on a hard switch full-bridge PWM circuit, but I don't have any experience on how to route it.

I'm worried that the terrible routing may influence the normal signal, such as the PWM signal. Could anyone give me some suggestions for breadboard routing?

[image]

The FET package I use is TO220.

[image]

The transformer is like this:

[image]

Comment: Alright, next, what current, voltage and frequency? got the transformer?

Comment: The frequency is about 50Khz. The input voltage is 50V. The primary current is -15~15A. I have two ouputs. One is about 10A, the other is about 3A. Have gotten the transformer, I will the picture. Thanks!

Comment: 50 kHz switcher on breadboard isn’t happening. Four layer PCBs are 5 USD these days. Fire up KiCad and design a tight layout for your circuit with ground planes.

Comment: @winny Thanks,winny, but I just want a preliminary verification of some idea, PCBs will take several days, and if there's something wrong with my PCB, correcting them will take more days. Using a breadboard is more faster and convenient for me now! Today I'm building the FET driver circuit and  I can start to route the main circuit tomorrow!

Comment: You will spend said days troubleshooting and replacing MOSFETs and gate drivers. Ask me how I know. I don’t want to rain on your parade, but the laws of physics at 50 kHz square waves are a blizzard of freezing acid rain with dead frogs raining down on said parade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done a H-bridge breadboard but it sure is possible to breadboard this kind of high speed stuff. It's quite annoying though.

So you take a piece of blank copper clad PCB which will be your ground plane.

Then you take a 1" wide roll of adhesive copper tape and a 1.5" wide roll of kapton tape. Stick the Kapton tape on the ground plane, stick the adhesive copper tape on top, and cut off the excess Kapton tape leaving about 1mm clearance around the copper.

This makes a power plane, and because the Kapton tape is very thin, it has extremely low inductance and decent capacitance to ground. Solder the SMD MLCC decoupling caps on the edges, between the power plane and ground plane, over the 1mm excess Kapton tape left over in the previous step.

That'll be the input and output voltage "copper pours". Then you can put the MOSFETs. If they need heatsinks... it's going to be complicated.

It's possible to make microstrips with wrapping wire and adhesive tape, you can even make coax if you use conductive adhesive copper tape to stick the wire to the ground plane.

To install the drivers, dead bug would work best, but power distribution is going to be an issue, because they need solid decoupling. Maybe you could make another power island with copper tape and straddle the drivers over the edge. Another solution is to mount the chips dead bug, with the 10µF MLCC decoupling cap tombstoned on the ground plane and soldered on the pin. But if you do your power distribution with wires, all those wire inductances will resonate with your caps, so it's best to replace critical wires with a few ohms resistors. Likewise for the MOSFET gate wires.

If you don't have copper tape you can also use a double sided blank coperclad PCB, put the power on the back and ground on top, and then make holes to thread a wire to power your chips. This has much worse inductance because the PCB is much thicker than the tape.

All in all, why not but it's very fiddly and a PCB sure is a lot more convenient.

Comment: Thanks! How about using the universal printed circuit board? Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Without planes you'll have high inductance, it'll be very problematic